# Getting the array as GET query parameters in Python

Tags: python, list, flask, request, werkzeug

I know in php I could just use `$_GET['key1']['key2']` to retrieve GET data that is sent in the form of an array but is that something possible in Python as I just receive a string and it's not recognized as an array/list.

I use flask/werkzeug if that matters.

Comment: Learn to read the question and what the people actually want before voting to close a question. I know how to get the request params, thats not what I asked about. Your url brings nothing new.

Comment: I didn't vote to close anything. After all I have less than 100 rep, so I can't do that. I gave you a link that might be helpful.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The deep parsing of argument names is unique for PHP AFAIK.

If you need just a simple list, just pass several parameters with the same name and use `request.args.getlist(<paramname>)` ([documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.args)).

Otherwise you have to parse the query string yourself.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Unfortunately I'm parsing an IPN from a payment gateway which sends arrays so I have to parse them as strings I believe.

Comment: IPN_REFNO[23456,23465]&IPN_TOTALAMOUNT[2133,3455]

Answer (score 68):

`request.args` is a MultiDict instance ([MultiDict](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), [Flask request api](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request)).

```
request.args[key] ## returns a single value, the first if there are multiple
request.args.getlist(key) ## returns a list
```

If you want to submit structures more complex than can be encoded using simple key:vals, consider sending a json encoded object.

Also, look at the jQuery recursive param serialisation [pattern](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/), and the [jquery-unparam](https://bitbucket.org/k_bx/jquery-unparam/overview) lib which can deserialise it.

Comment: getlist would help if all vars are passed as `&var[]=1&var[]=2...`. In this case, I'd simply use `request.args.getlist('var[]')`. If params are passed with keys, however: `&var[0]=1&var[1]=2...` — it becomes an issue…

Comment: Hi...!!! I was using this and it wasn't working, I was using the brackets. Thanks a lot because it wasn't obvious and now is working fine :)